# Docker containers-ID got change on each startup of container

Tags: docker

I have started working with docker and I faced a problem whenever i start a container it provides a ID but when the container goes down and after new startup this starts with new ID, in this case the data/logs belongs to last start-up gets lost. Is this possible to fix the containers-ID ?

Comment: Ideally the container is stateless and your data/logs is mapped into it from the outside. Then you can start a new container process to pick up where the previous one left off.

Comment: actually what i have faced when ever i mount a data/log directory the log and data is not going to save over local host all the logs/data save with container. If you want to see your log you have to find container-ID and then go to the path of container there you find data and logs. And if your container goes down because of any reason on new startup the container-ID get change and old data is saved with old container-ID which is located in /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/Container-ID

Comment: yes. don't put your logs and data into the container. put it into a data volume attached to the container. for logs, you can also send them out (via stdout, or syslog, or whatever)

Comment: as m running elasticsearch image on docker so is there any option to keep your data safe with running container and what if the container goes down.
I am running es like this:
docker run -d -p 9100:9200 -p 9101:9300 -v /home/data2/:/data walm/elasticsearch /opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Des.config=/data/elasticsearch.yml
 
i have two major problem:
1) how to save data/log on local machine because when i start es with that command, data/log get save with the container .
2) Are we able to fix the container-ID, whenever i start es it starts with same container-ID which was earlier..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean the container name? Use the option `--name`

Here is the sample that you can reserve the same name when start the container. But you need make sure that no container with same name is running.

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag
```

Second, if you need manage logs, then

1. create a seperate log volume and mount it with container.
2. export the log to ELK/splunk

If you need some solutions now, try this repository

```
https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout
Log routing for Docker container logs
```

Comment: no not container name, i mean container id which docker generates whenever any images runs. we check the containers-ID with : docker ps
which provides the info about running container and the container-ID.

Comment: Then your direction is wrong. Think to use docker name to manage.